# Python Sellenium Chromedrive - can't set up the path (InstaPy)

Tags: python, selenium, automation, instagram, selenium-chromedriver

I am playing around with this repo:

https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy

I have cloned the repo, installed Python 3.6, Selenium, py virtual driver (Although I am not sure if I have to save it somewhere).

I have two questions: 
1) How do I set up a path for PY command? -- What does that mean exactly? And what does it do? I have googled that, and I don't have any Python experience so I am having a hard time understanding it.
2) I have downloaded chromedriver and put it in the assets, but I am having trouble figuring out if what I put there makes sense.

When I run `chromedriver`, I get this error: `Only local connections are allowed.
[0.011][SEVERE]: bind() returned an error, errno=48: Address already in use (48)`. I have tried killing it, but it says there's nothing to kill.

And when I run `python quickstart.py`, I get this error `Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`, which I am assuming is related to the fact that I didn't set a path.

If I run `python instapy/login_util.py`, I get `File "instapy/login_util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .time_util import sleep
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`.

Sorry for the long message, I am just hoping to understand everything. I have read the docs and questions from the repo, but I still feel very confused

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the path for chrome driver

import os
os.environ["Selenium_Chrom_Path"] = "/foo/path_to_chrome_exec"